# Counter set or rows with the same numbering based on condition

Tags: python, counter

I have dataset. For a certain condition there is a column has True or False values. If there is a sequence of rows has the same value, then let the counter of these rows be the same.

To make it clear, below is my code:

```
c1 = [True,True,False,False,False,True,False,True,True,False,True]
counter = 1
switch = 0 #increase the counter when the vector has switched twice
c2 = np.repeat(None, len(c1))
c2[i]=counter

for i in range(1,len(c1)):
    p = c1[i-1]
    x = c1[i]
    if p==x:
        counter=counter
        c2[i]=counter


    if p!=x : 
        switch = switch + 1

        c2[i]=switch



    elif switch == 2: 
            counter = counter + 1  

            switch = 0 #reset the counter


print(c2)
```

The actual output is

```
[None 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 1 5 6]
```

while the expected one should be

```
[None, 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]
```

Comment: You said: 'If there is a sequence of rows has the same value, then let the counter of these rows be the same.' From this, I understand the counter should increase each time the boolean switch from true to false and viceversa. So the expected output should be: [1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 5 6 7]. Why your expected output is halved?

Comment: Because the first Boolean has a none value as I compare next to previous, also, my counter is splitting between True, and False. In other words, True has counter and False has counter each of which starts from 1. @Valentino

Comment: Comparing next to previous is not necessary the right thing to do, it depends on what is the logic of your counter, which I still fail to grasp. Now seems you want to count the numbers of True and False separately, but this will give an expected output of `[1 2 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6]` still different from what you said. From you expected output, it seems to me you just want to count when the boolean switch from False to True.

Answer (score 0):

```
 c1 = [True,True,False,False,False,True,False,True,True,False,True]
 res = []
 var = 1

 cur=c1[0]
 flag = 0
 res.append(None)

 for val in c1[1:]:
     if val==cur and flag == 0:
         res.append(var)
     elif val == cur and flag == 1:
         var+=1
         flag = 0
         res.append(var)
     elif val != cur and flag == 0:
         flag = 1
         res.append(var)
     elif val != cur and flag == 1:
         res.append(var)
     else:
         pass

 print(res)
```

Output:[None, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]